# Override all form element styles like HTML+CSS

Tags: android, styles

In HTML/CSS you can override all paragraphs by defining p in CSS

I.e.
`p { color: blue;
}`

Can you do mimc this in Android?  I'd like to define my set of styles for all form elements in styles.xml and then every layout I write would use these properties.

At the moment I have to specify the style in the layout: i.e

`<EditText android:id="@+id/address1" style="@style/EditText" />`

Which seems a bit redundant (and error prone).

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an **xml** file which defines the style that you want, and store it in **res/values** folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is an example of an style, once you have your style. you can applay it to every view by doing something like this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

This example is from:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Thanks! So declaring custom name <styles> I can replicate what classes do in CSS?